# php filter content to find span with specific id

Tags: php, regex

i have content. there is too many spans.
i want to get content of span which has **id='credit-id'**. 
for example:  535

i want to get the content of the span which has id credit-id.

how to do that?

i tried preg_match method but not getting  out put. getting blank array.

```
 preg_match_all('/<span id=\"credit\-id\">(.*?)<\/span>/s',$file_contents,$estimates);
```

getting blank array;

```
  ARRAY()
```

Comment: You say you want to get `id='credit-id'` but check for `id="credit-id"` - are you sure the attributes value is enclosed by `"` (and not `'`) in your actual page?

Comment: Not all characters you have escaped have to be escaped. I made a test regex, [here](http://regexr.com?370a8) This regex tool can help you build your regex patterns with a clear visual and good explanation as to what does what. Furthermore, how are you using this preg_match_all? In an `ob_start();`?

Comment: i am not sure about preg_match. do you know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

See [this fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/y5e-dzg).

Important to note is the regex in combination with the `'`-enclosure of the spans id attribute:

```
/<span id='credit-id'>(.*?)<\/span>/
```

If your spans id attribute is enclosed with `"` instead of `'`, then you have to edit the regular expression. And if you do, don't forget to escape the double quotation marks.